# R - applying calculation pairwise on columns of data frame/data table

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

Let's say I have the data frames with the same column names

```
DF1 = data.frame(a = c(0,1), b = c(2,3), c = c(4,5))

DF2 = data.frame(a = c(6,7), c = c(8,9))
```

and want to apply some basic calculation on them, for example add each column.

Since I also want the goal data frame to display missing data, I appended such a column to DF2, so I have

```
> DF2
  a c  b
1 6 8 NA
2 7 9 NA
```

What I tried here now is to create the data frame

```
for(i in names(DF2)){
   DF3 = data.frame(i = DF1[i] + DF2[i])
}
```

(and then bind this together) but this obviously doesn't work since the order of the columns is mashed up.

**SO,**
what's the best way to do this pairwise calculation when the order of the columns is not the same, without reordering them?

I also tried doing (since this is what I thought would be a fix)

```
for(i in names(DF2)){
    DF3 = data.frame(i = DF1$i + DF2$i)
}
```

but this doesn't work because `DF1$i` is `NULL` for all `i`.

---

Conlusion: I want the data frame

```
>DF3
  a   b  c
1 6+0 NA 4+8
2 1+7 NA 5+9
```

---

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help -

```
#Get column names from DF1 and DF2
all_cols <- union(names(DF1), names(DF2))

#Fill missing columns with NA in both the dataframe
DF1[setdiff(all_cols, names(DF1))] <- NA
DF2[setdiff(all_cols, names(DF2))] <- NA

#add the two dataframes arranging the columns
DF1[all_cols] + DF2[all_cols]

#  a  b  c
#1 6 NA 12
#2 8 NA 14
```

Comment: Almost! I would prefer if NA stayed NA

Comment: Instead of 0 you can replace it with `NA`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
bind_rows(DF1, DF2, .id = 'grp') %>% 
    group_by(grp = rowid(grp)) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), sum), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     6    NA    12
2     8    NA    14
```

Comment: Great answer with great idea. I followed the same path but have to use longer code :)

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `aggregate` + `stack` + `reshae`

```
aggregate(
  . ~ rid,
  transform(
    reshape(
      transform(rbind(
        stack(DF1),
        stack(DF2)
      ),
      rid = ave(seq_along(ind), ind, FUN = seq_along)
      ),
      direction = "wide",
      idvar = "rid",
      timevar = "ind"
    ),
    rid = 1:nrow(DF1)
  ),
  sum,
  na.action = "na.pass"
)[-1]
```

gives

```
  values.a values.b values.c
1        6       NA       12
2        8       NA       14
```